# load data using sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Need a quick help.
I have a file which contains huge pipe separated data.
I want to load each line of the data file to a column in a table.
But each line in data file is having multiple pipes.
previoulsy while loading data I was loading to multiple columns using pipe as delimiter using below control file query.

```
LOAD DATA 
INTO TABLE sc8157.tmp_analysis_01
APPEND 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
  ABD_ERRORMESSAGE,
  ISSUE_NO CONSTANT 'FIT-33266_all'
)
```

But now I want to load entire line to one column. Can anyone help me in writing the query for the control file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want each line in the file to be a different column in the same table? How many columns are there, and will the file have one value for each column - or multiple rows of data? A simplified example would be useful, with a small table and file (the value don't have to be huge...)

Comment: maybe try using tab as delimiter (assuming there are no actual tabs in the file), then the entire line should map to the single column you specify.  Use: fields terminated by x'09'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easier way will be change the separator in your input file.
You must have the same number of parameters in your input file and in your CTL file.

If the separator in your input file and your CTL file is different, the entire line will be inserted in one column.

Comment: Actually you do not have to have the same number of fields in the file as fields in the control file.  As proof I altered the control file as given in my example to have the fields terminated by '|' as the only change then ran the load with my 4 column data file.  Only column "cola" loaded. Otherwise FILLER, BOUNDFILLER, etc clauses would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell sqlldr the field separator is a carriage return.  In this working example table "test" has 4 columns.  File test.dat also has 4 pipe-delimited columns.  Sqlldr just sees one column in the data since I told it the carriage return ended the field.  The control file just specified one field which matched a column name  in the table so that's where it inserted the data.

```
LOAD DATA
infile "test.dat"
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY x'0D'
(cola char(1000)
)
```

Oh and be aware that you should put the size of the field as defined in the table  after the "char" in the control file else sqlldr uses a relatively small default value value (256?) and will throw a "field too small" or something like that error which will drive you crazy trying to track down.  I am surprised sqlldr doesn't automatically query the system tables to get the actual column size and use that.  Perhaps there's a good reason.  Anyway I will edit my example.  Also VARCHAR2's have a size limit of 4000 characters so you said you have a huge row you could face size restrictions.